# For $\cal{F}=\{g:D(g,f)\leq\epsilon\}$ is there any density $\hat{g}\in\cal{F}$ with CDF $\hat{G}(y)>G(y)\forall y$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions

More clearly given a closed ball $$\cal{F}=\{g:D(g,f)\leq\epsilon\}$$ with some distance measure say relative entropy $$D(g,f)=\int g(y)\log\left(\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}\right)\mathrm{d}y$$ is there any denstiy function $\hat{g}\in\cal{F}$ whose cumulative distribution function (CDF) $\hat{G}$ is larger than any other density function's CDF $G$ in the closed ball, i.e., $\hat{G}(y)>G(y)\forall y$ ?

I did some simulations and it seems that the claim is incorrect but how one can show it? in addition to this does the distance $\cal{D}$ matter?

Thanks for reading this post and for any hint

Answer (score 1):

Let me take: $T = \{g:D(g,f)≤ϵ\}$

$$D(g,f)=\int g(y)\log\left(\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}\right)dy$$

Note: $D(g,f) =∫g(y)\log(g(y)/f(y))dy$

$\log(g(y)/f(y))$ is a weakly increasing function of $y$ in $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

For a density function $g \in T$ with its cdf $G$ to be larger than any other cdf's (say an arbitrary cdf $F$ different from $G$) in $T$, i.e., $G(y) > F(y)$ for all $y$, $F$ must first-order stochastically dominate $G$.

A necessary and sufficient condition for $F$ first-order stochastically dominates $G$ is that for every weakly increasing $h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $\int h(y)dF(y)\geq ∫h(y)dG(y)$

Let's try to see if $\int h(y)dF(y) \geq \int h(y)dG(y)$ is a plausible inequality under the closed ball $T$.

Assume $\int h(y)dF(y) \geq \int h(y)dG(y)$

Take, $h(y) = \log(g(y)/f(y))$; so that, $\int h(y)dF(y) \geq D(g,f)$

$\int h(y)dF(y) = E[\log(g(y)/f(y))]$ where expectation is taken w.r.t. the cdf $F$

By Jensen's inequality, $E[\log(g(y)/f(y))] \leq \log(E[g(y)/f(y)])$ as logarithm is a concave (downward) function.

Note: $\log(E[g(y)/f(y)]) = \log(\int g(y)dy) = 0$ [I just used the definition of expectation of a continuous rv]

So, $E[\log(g(y)/f(y))] \leq 0$; Thus, $\int h(y)dF(y) \leq 0$; Hence $D(g,f) \leq 0$. But this is not possible for a distance metric.

Hence our initial assumption that $\int h(y)dF(y) \geq \int h(y)dG(y)$ is not correct. So, it is not true that $G(y) > F(y)$ for all $y$ [Recall the necessary & sufficient condition for stochastic dominance].

Hope my solution makes sense to you.

Regarding the choice of the distance metric, can you now think if that really matters?

Regards,

Sauvik

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just edited, please see if there is a mistake in the edit.

Comment: $log(g(y)/f(y))$ is a weakly increasing function of y in R→R is an **incorrect** assumption. usually the expectation would be that $log(f(y)/g(y))$ is weakly increasing especially when we are looking for some $G$ which is $G(y)>F(y)$. If we assume the otherway around as you suggested $G(y)>F(y)$ will authomatically will not be satisfied for some $y$ just due to the assumtion $log(g(y)/f(y))$, as a result the proof is flawed, although I believe that there exists no such density.