# How to show that a closed ball doesn't allow stochastical ordering

Tags: general-topology, probability-distributions

Given a closed ball $$\cal{F}=\{g:D(g,f)\leq\epsilon\}$$ where $f$ and $g$ are some density functions and $D$ some distance say relative entropy: $$D(g,f)=\int g(y)\log\left(\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}\right)\mathrm{d}y$$

> **Question:** Is there any denstiy function $\hat{g}\in\cal{F}$ whose cumulative distribution function (CDF) $\hat{G}$ is larger than any other density function's CDF $G$ in the closed ball, i.e., $\hat{G}(y)>G(y)\forall y$ ?

The answer is easy if $\log\left({g(y)}/{f(y)}\right)$ is [monotone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548930/for-calf-gdg-f-leq-epsilon-is-there-any-density-hatg-in-calf). But such a constraint makes no sense. Any comment is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an exact answer you're looking for but maybe will lead somewhere.

Consider bernoulli distributions $f$ and $g$ such that  $g \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathbb{E}_f X \geq\mathbb{E}_g X$. Denote the set of such distributions be $\mathcal{G}$.
It is known that for bernoulli distribution, $\Pr(X \leq t) \leq \Pr(Y \leq t)$ for all $t$ if $\mathbb{E}X \geq \mathbb{E}Y$. Then for any $g'$ and $g$ where $D(g,f)\leq D(g',f)$, 
$$
\mathbb{E}_g X \geq \mathbb{E}_{g^\prime} X.
$$
So we choose $\hat{g}$ such that $D(\hat{g},f)=\epsilon$, then
 $F(x) \leq G(x) \leq \hat{G}(x)$ for all $x$ and all $g\in \mathcal{G}\in \mathcal{F}$.

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thx. For the general case there is no such domination. Btw, did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: You mean for all general case, the question is true ? For my question I posted, I did not get any answer yet. I have an idea how to solve it but was stuck at a step and I haven't revisited since.

Comment: Yes, for the general case, on real numbers. I can tell it very shortly. In a Lagrangian optimization setting, it is possible to show that there exists a unique distribution which maximizes the expected value. This is almost the same with your argument. Then, for the general case stochastic ordering suggests that only expectation condition is not enough to argue about the stochastic ordering. In fact one needs to show that for every increasing function of the random variable the stochastic ordering must hold. For any other function applied to the random variable, again Lagrangian optimization

Comment: says that there exists another density different from the one which maximizes the expectation. Therefore, the one which maximizes the expectation cannot be stochastically larger than all other distributions. Btw, Your question sounds interesting to me. I will think about it..

Comment: Yes, you're right. With only expectation, it is not enough to argue for first order stochastic dominance. By the way, which question do you meant ? I posted two questions before. Is it the one on math.stackexchange on "Sum of independent (not necessary identical) Bernoulli" ?

Comment: Yes "poisson Binomial approximated by..." I have some similar problem but it is a bit different-

Comment: Oh ok. Let me know if you anything interesting. I am particularly interested in that distribution. Thanks for looking at my problem.