# two soft questions about stochastical ordering

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I have two questions and I will be very happy to hear your comments:

> **a-)** For two random variables $X$ and $Y$ let $X$ dominate $Y$, i.e. $X>_{ST}Y$. let $f$ be a positive function. Is it true that $f(X)$ stochastically dominate $f(Y)$, i.e. $f(X)>_{ST}f(Y)$?
>
> **b-)** For two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which do not stochastically dominate each other, is there are function $f$ such that $f(X)$ stochastically dominate $f(Y)$?

Thanks in advance.

**What I know:**

For part **a-)** I know that if $f$ is non-decreasing, then the domination is preserved.

For part **b-)** I know that an $f$ function exists such that $E[f(X)]\geq E[f(Y)]$ but this is in expectation not in CDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) No, the domination is not preserved. For example take $X=1$ (has a dirac measure on $1$) and $Y \sim U[1,2]$. Then $Y$ stochastically dominates $X$. But now let $f: [1,2] \to \mathbb R, f(x) = \frac{1}{x} > 0 $ then the exact opposite relation holds for $f(X)=X=1$ and $f(Y) \leq 1$.

b) A trivial example would be a constant function. Else, you could just construct a function appropriately operating on the set $\{t\in\mathbb R: F_X(t) \leq F_Y(t)\}$ (and leaving the rest constant), which is not empty because of your assumption.

edit: More detailed example for b)
Let $X \sim \frac{1}{2} (\delta_0 + \delta_2)$ and $Y \sim \delta_1$ ($\delta_x$ is denotes the dirac measure concentrated at $x$). Then $X, Y$ can't be stochastically ordered. But let $f(x) = 1_{\{x \geq 2\}}$, then you get a strict inequality of the distribution functions of $f(X), f(Y)$ for $t \in [0,1)$, i.e.

$$F_{f(Y)}(t) = 1 \;\forall t \in [0,1)$$, while

$$F_{f(X)}(t) = \frac{1}{2} \;\forall t \in [0,1)$$

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes it is also what i thought so. So for a constant function we have $\leq$ case. I was wondering an example where $F_X(y)<F_Y(y)$. Do you have in mind any example?

Comment: no problem! Edited the post to add a more detailed example for b).

Comment: Okay no need to restrict to $[0,1)$ at the end of the interval of interest we will eventually get $\leq$. Thx for the answer. I have another question about stochastical ordering. Please let me know if you have any idea: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015343/how-to-show-that-a-closed-ball-doesnt-allow-stochastical-ordering